# Unique male and female count who posted vote

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I want to display the unqiue gender who has voted and user is allowed to vote multiple times, there are multiple records in items_votes with same user_id.

The query below return the number of male and female counts but it is not unqiue as it counts the gender for user multiple times if same male user voted multiple times.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN items_votes.user_id END) AS males,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN items_votes.user_id END) AS females
    FROM items_votes
    INNER JOIN users_profiles
    ON items_votes.user_id = users_profiles.user_id
    WHERE item_id = 5
```

I want the unique count of males and females from above query.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you GROUP BY sex and SELECT DISTINCT?  That seems more natural to me.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Can't you see "Mysql" in the title of the post? :)

Comment: @Shahid Actually I didnt. I subscribe to tags, that is how I get the question Im interested on. You shouldnt put database on title

Comment: So if you use MySQL, why do you tag MS SQL Server?

Comment: @duffymo, combine GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT - how?

Answer (score 4):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4b2ce/2)**

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `sex` = 'M' THEN `user_id` END) as maleCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `sex` = 'F' THEN `user_id` END) as femaleCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `sex` = 'M' THEN `user_id` END) as uniqueMaleCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `sex` = 'F' THEN `user_id` END) as uniqueFemaleCount
FROM item
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| maleCount | femaleCount | uniqueMaleCount | uniqueFemaleCount |
|-----------|-------------|-----------------|-------------------|
|         5 |           5 |               3 |                 2 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(items_votes.user_id)) AS votes, sex
FROM items_votes
INNER JOIN users_profiles
ON items_votes.user_id = users_profiles.user_id
WHERE item_id = 5
GROUP BY sex;
```

Comment: That doesn't return unqiue counts. COUNT(items_votes.user_id) as i wrote there can be muliple records with same user_id. but COUNT(DISTINCT(items_votes.user_id)) with your query works. thanks